# Is there a way to associate arbitrary data to a Windows Process?

Tags: c#, windows, process, windows-server-2012

I have many instances of a process I've written on a server. I'd like to associate some information with each process. In this specific case I'd like to store the "CurrentState" of the process - "RUNNING|DRAINING|STOPPING", but it would be useful for me to store a "Friendly Name" and so on.

I want to query this information from another "mother" process - this mother process will query the processes running and collate the data.

I've thought of a couple of different ways I could achieve this. For example I might open up a NetPipe to each process of interest and ask for the data, or have each process broadcast it's state regularly.

I was wondering: is there a way to store key value pair information against a process built into Windows itself? Is there an accepted pattern for doing this?

I control the source for the child processes and the mother process. They are written in C#, P/Invoking is fine. The operating system is Windows 2012 R2.

Comment: Have you considered using Tasks http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx. Processes and the burdens of interprocess communication are expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can host WCF services that use named pipes:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Based on some of your comments, it looks like you could also consider the [System.AddIn (aka Managed AddIn Framework (MAF))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145020%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) functionality to create, host, and communicate with Add-ins.  MAF supports loading addins in your app domain, a separate app domain, or in a completely separate process.  The downside with MAF is that it requires 5 DLLs to get started, but in doing that gives you a lot of flexibility with API compatibility as you version and change your pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

If you're controlling the data from a Mother process, you can also use [AppDomains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) to [load your other processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and communicate via [Marhsaled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx) data such as a Status class, or use the AppDomains to [Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37z40s1c.aspx) and [Get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getdata.aspx) data.

Be aware that any Status data you transfer needs to either be a class which derives from the Marshaling class or be marked as [Serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx). The reason for this is because AppDomains are treated in the OS the same as different processes, so they can't access each others memory an actually have to serialize data as if it were being passed through IPC.

Comment: In the first incarnation of my project I used application domains as you have suggested. In practice this wasn't reliable enough, exceptions in the child application domains can affect the stability of the host (for example a Stack Overflow exception). So I use Process isolation now.

Comment: In that case, I recommend IPC. Perhaps the most secure way you could do so is to send arguments to the child process when you start it, including a GUID. Use that GUID as the identifier for a Named Pipe via WCF, and make the child process connect the pipe to the parent.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the .Net Process Class:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can use it to get all running processes, start a process, get the processes unique Id, and be alerted when the process exits. This should give you everything you need to track processes.

Children can call [Process.GetCurrentProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get their own process id, then make a call to the "mother" process to associate arbitrary data about itself.

Comment: Thanks Eric, but the .Net Process Class, doesn't give me a way to associate arbitrary data about the process; I want the children to update this arbitrary data.

Comment: @Daniel James Bryars Does that help?

Comment: +1 thank you for your suggestion. I'm really interested though in knowing if there is an arbitrary way to associate the data in Windows as per my specific question.

Comment: No problem. I couldn't find anything to do exactly what you are looking for. My concern using that method would be that a process may change its custom properties and the mother process may not pick it up if the process exits, also the mother process will have to be constantly polling to get new or changed properties versus the way I suggest which adheres to the [Hollywood principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollywood_principle).